# How can I calculate the number of checkboxes selected inside a repeating section in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to give a discount based on the number of camp sessions signed up for in a repeating section but can't figure out the formula for doing that.  Help?

In the repeating section called "Camper Information" I have a choice box called "sessions":

```
Sessions

July 1-5 $225

July 7-12 $225

July 14-19 $225

July 21-26 $225
```

I'm trying to make a calculation that will do:

```
number of sessions > 1 but < 3 gives a 5% discount

number of sessions > 4 gives a 10% discount
```

https://www.cognitoforms.com/Edenacres1/SummerOutdoorsSignUpForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calculations](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/calculations) for [Repeating Sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), allow you to easily filter and total lists of structured information.

You can find detailed documentation for calculations involving repeating sections here:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/51/calculations/repeating-sectionstables

For your specific example, the following calculation will automatically calculate the number of selected sessions across all repeating sections:

`=CamperInformation.Sum(Sessions.Count)`

You can then use this inside a discount calculation for a Price field outside of the repeating section as follows:

```
=(
   if CamperInformation.Sum(Sessions.Count) > 3 then -0.1 
   else if CamperInformation.Sum(Sessions.Count) > 1 then -0.05 
   else 0
 ) *
 CamperInformation.Sum(Sessions_Amount)
```

Comment: Talk about kindness from strangers.  Thanks so much, the formula worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked!!!